# Matlab Optimization, Alternatives for 'any' function

Tags: matlab, optimization

Is there any way I could optimize the following code.
[image]

The function above is a nested function, finalBin2Grey is a cell, rest all are simple doubles and arrays.

[image]

Also the MATLAB pro-filer shows that all other lines in function as 41.122 s. But there is no such line/lines that occupies that time. Is this the overhead of calling function or am I missing something.?

EDIT:
Here is a high level over-view of what the function does:

Checks if the `grayLevel` lie between `upperLimit` and `lowerLimit`, if so returns true.

Also the `grayLevel` cannot be equal to `upperLimit`or `lowerLimit` for it to be true.

Cell `finalBin2grey` contains a double or array of doubles depending on the index.

Comment: "But there is no such line/lines that occupies that time" - er, what about "all" the "other lines" that _aren't_ those 5 where "most time was spent"? You've even shown us some of them, so I guarantee they exist ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't be sure that it's `any`. It may well be the use of `==`. Here are a few options to try (It's nearly impossible to provide concrete help without a [minimal, complete, tested and readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

I'm not sure you need the second `if`/`else` statement at all. The following would be sufficient:

```
bool = any(grayLevel>lowerLimit) && any(grayLevel<upperLimit);
```

It returns `true` only if any `grayLevel` is strictly between the limits and zero otherwise. You might want to replace `>` with `>=` or `<` with `<=` to be sure not to miss points on the edges.

Comment: Unfortunately that line fails to capture the "nothing equals a limit, but at least _something_ is above lowerLimit and at least _something_ is below upperLimit" behaviour. Of course, the more I look at that the more it makes no sense, since it can be true even if nothing is _between_ both limits, which is very much at odds with the function name...

Comment: Also any idea why accessing a cell array takes up so much time.?

Comment: @polavarapu: It's hard to say more without knowing how the function is used/called and what the inputs are. But looking at the number of calls (over 4.5 million!) it seems that your actual issue is that you need to vectorize. Your time per call isn't that bad.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for the tip about if/else. The suggestion about 'any' has bit of logical flaw though. I corrected it and the if/else tip did pay off, gave about 30s boost.!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've re-invented HISTC or IMHIST. The whole routine might be optimizable by using one of those instead.

Comment: No. The above function is completely different from imhist and histc